# Two common elements between lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a problem with this function `two-similar-p`.

```
(defun two-similar-p (list1 list2) 
  (mapcar 
   (lambda (e) 
     (mapcar 
      (lambda (e1)
        (if (equal e e1) t))
      list2))
   list1))
```

But is not correct use `mapcar` because this function returns a new list with `T` or `NIL`, but I need only to return a true or false.

ex.

```
(two-similar-p '(2 1 3) '(1 2 3))
==> ((NIL T NIL) (T NIL NIL) (NIL NIL T))
```

I was thinking to use recursion to compare the various elements, but I have no idea how to do that.
My function needs to work like:

```
(two-similar-p '(1 2 3) '(1 4 5)) ; ==> nil

(two-similar-p '(1 2 5) '(1 4 5)) ; ==> t

(two-similar-p '(1 2 6) '(6 4 2)) ; ==> t
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why does the first example return `nil`?

Comment: ops, sorry, first example return nil because they don't have at least two equal elements.

Comment: are you required to use `mapcar`?

Comment: no, i was thinking (incorrectly) to use a "double" mapcar function for compare the first element of list 1 with the elements of list 2. the same thing for the second element of list 1 with the elements of list 2 ecc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest "off-the-shelf" solution is to check that the [`intersection`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_isec_.htm) contains at least two elements:

```
(defun two-similar-p (l1 l2)
  (consp (cdr (intersection l1 l2 :test #'equal))))
```

A slightly less OTS solution is to use [hash tables](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm):

```
(defun two-similar-p (l1 l2)
  (let ((h1 (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
        (common 0))
    (dolist (x l1)
      (setf (gethash x h1) t))
    (dolist (x l2)
      (when (gethash x h1)
        (incf common))
      (when (>= common 2)
        (return t)))))
```

The advantage of the second approach is that its complexity is `O(len(l1) + len(l2))`,
while the `mapcar` approach will be `O(len(l1) * len(l2))`.

The standard does not specify the complexity of `intersection` and [friends](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/14_abb.htm), but most implementations take good care of their users here (IOW, the complexity will be linear, not quadratic).

Comment: thank u very much! i am using the first solution and all work